# Shall we remove [appinsights] tag? Or just add it as a synonym?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

The tag [appinsights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appinsights) is clearly a duplicate of the tag [azure-application-insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-application-insights). Let's just kill it, maybe?

Comment: You retagged all 7 questions that had that tag?

Comment: @rene - yes, all 32 of them to be precise. Now this tag is empty.

Comment: And thanks for that link. I did not know that we have automatic tag deletion procedure